# PFX to JKS keytool conversion: Alias <*> does not exist

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, keytool, pfx, jks

I'm trying to convert x.PFX file to x.JKS file using keytool but I am getting following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <2> does not exist
```

Actions that preceded this error are:

**Listing x.PFX file content (just to read alias name):**

```
keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore x.pfx

Enter keystore password: x

Keystore type: PKCS12   
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: 2
Creation date: 11-nov-2012

Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=x, OU=x, C=x
Issuer: CN=x, O=x, C=x
Serial number: x
Valid from: Wed Oct 24 11:46:10 CEST 2012 until: Fri Dec 13 09:28:40 CET 2013
Certificate fingerprints:

etc.
```

**Converting x.PFX file into x.JKS file using "2" as source alias name**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore x.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias 2 -destkeystore x.jks -deststoretype jks -destalias xyz
Enter destination keystore password: y
Re-enter new password: y
Enter source keystore password: x
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <2> does not exist
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? PFX file contain only one entry with just one alias (2). I also tried using these srcalias values: 2, "2", " 2". Is there any other way to convert PFX into JKS using keytool without knowing source alias name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I've solved using '1' instead of 2. Don't know why but it worked.

Answer (score 8):

if set alias in pkcs12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey private_key.pem -out keystore.p12 -name "myalias"
```

aftet alias setted successfully:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -alias myalias
```

Comment: This was the answer that helped me, as the name was not set in my pkcs12; once set in the pkcs12, the JKS was able to be created using my desired alias name.

Answer (score 3):

your command should looks a bit more like this

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore x.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -***alias*** 2 -destkeystore x.jks -deststoretype jks -destalias xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe "2" can't be found, because there are whitespaces included (e.g. "2 ")

If you don't wanna change the alias just remove the options *-srcalias* and *-destalias* and it will be imported with the original alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keytool to list the aliases within your `*.pfx` file, just use the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore yourPrivateCertificate.pfx
```

This will give you something like this:

```
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

253db30c3ad14553aebb0e5a0a5255d0_e5345748-fe48-42ac-81e7-b48cfb4610dd, Nov 25, 2019, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 
A9:3B:80:3C:D9:63:0E:FF:91:72:AC:11:4B:45:99:14:9E:AD:EC:FB
```

So in the case above, the following is the alias:

```
253db30c3ad14553aebb0e5a0a5255d0_e5345748-fe48-42ac-81e7-b48cfb4610dd
```

This value needs to be used for the source alias