# Java Keystore PrivateKeyEntry vs trustedCertEntry

Tags: security, hadoop, ssl, jks

I'm renewing a certificate used by my Hadoop cluster.
Current JKS has one entry:

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myalias
Creation date: Jan 10, 2019
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
```

I'm trying to create a new keystore from the new cert:

```
keytool -importcert -alias myalias  -file newcertfile.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks
```

But I get asked about whether I trust this certificate (If I say no, keytool quits):

```
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
```

And when I look at the result, it's no longer a PrivateKeyEntry but a trustedCertEntry:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore newkeystore.jks
...
...
Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myalias
Creation date: Feb 20, 2019
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
...
...
```

What am I missing here?
Should I just use the JKS with the trustedCertEntry or is there a way to make it just like the old JKS (with PrivateKeyEntry)?

Comment: Use the same alias the private key already had.  Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974324/import-certificate-as-privatekeyentry

Comment: Thank you. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I eventually figured out that I have to supply the private key as well (As [Roshith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3114854/roshith) mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974324/import-certificate-as-privatekeyentry) he supplied).

So I started with first creating a pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out newcertbundle.pfx -inkey myprivate.key -in newcertfile.crt
```

And then converted it to jks:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore newcertbundle.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass mypass -deststorepass mypass -destkeypass mypass -destkeystore newkeystore.jks
```

The only thing I couldn't figure out (but wasn't too important to me) was how to use an alias, so I went with a default one (when I tried specifying one I got: Alias  does not exist. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334422/pfx-to-jks-keytool-conversion-alias-does-not-exist)).

Comment: You got the alias doesn't exist because you dint provide one when exporting the pfx, you need to provide a `-name <ALIAS>` on your `openssl pkcs12 export` command and provde `-alias <ALIAS>` in your `keytool` command.