# Keytool, retrieve the alias value as string from a JKS or from a PFX

Tags: java, powershell, keytool

I'm running a Powershell script that is updating a properties file in a java application and using Keytool to convert keys from PFX to JKS format.

I'm trying to convert a PFX to a JKS. I can't specify -"destalias" without specifying "-srcalias". The certificate being a PFX, I don't think it has an alias, but only a fingerprint.

However Keytool seems to see that the PFX has an Alias and it's using that value to auto-populate the Alias value of the JKS file.

I need the value of the Alias as a string to update my properties file.

Question:

Is there a way using Keytool or Powershell to either get the alias value from a PFX or a JKS as a String value.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

`keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore x.pfx`

To see the Alias , generally it will be some number like 1 or 2 , you can then use this in your command for "-srcalias"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I need everything to be run by the script. Your solution involves me copying manually the alias value.

Comment: You can run the command within the script and parse out the value , see this stackoverflow question for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334422/pfx-to-jks-keytool-conversion-alias-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keytool -list` to get the information out of the PFX, and use `Select-String` with a Regex expression to read it automatically from `keytool`.

```
$alias = (
        keytool -list -keystore $pfxFile -storepass $pass -v |
        Select-String -Pattern "Alias name: (.+)"
    ).Matches.Groups |
    select -Skip 1 -First 1 -ExpandProperty Value;
```

This looks for a string beginning `Alias name:` , followed by any characters in a group, and then takes the first group ignoring the outer match group.

Check `$LASTEXITCODE -ne 0` to see if it failed.